# How do I wrap nlohmann json objects with additional layers of keys from a vector of key names?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I have a vector of key names, how do I create a json of these nested keys, such that it's like:

```
std::vector<std::string> keys = {"a", "b", "c"};

json myJson = createJson (keys);
```

the resulting json I want

```
{
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then after that, I want to be able to modify the deepest layer of myjson later in code, equivalent to:

```
myJson["a"]["b"]["c"].merge_patch(newJson1)
myJson["a"]["b"]["c"].merge_patch(newJson2)
```

However, the size of my key vector is variable, so I can't hardcode the `["a"]["b"]["c"]` part, I basically need some way to for loop through each key until I reach the end, and then do my update on that last element.

So far I solved createJson by looping through the keys in reverse and just creating new jsons, but this feels very inefficient as it looks like I'm creating a bunch of new jsons and a lot of copys:

```
json createJson (const std::vector<std::string> &keys) {
    json j = json::value_t::object;
    for (auto it = keys.rbegin(); it != keys.rend(); it++) {
        json temp;
        temp[*it] = j;
        j = temp;
    }
    return j;
}
```

But now I don't have access to the deepest layer of the json anymore. What I then did is:

```
json createJson (const std::vector<std::string> &keys, json & j) {
    for (auto it = keys.rbegin(); it != keys.rend(); it++) {
        json temp;
        temp[*it] = j;
        j = temp;
    }
}

json j;
createJson(newJson1);
createJson(newJson2);
j.merge_patch(newJson1);
j.merge_patch(newJson2);
```

Which works, but seems kind of dumb because now instead of just modifying the deepest json nest, merge_patch is merging across all the keys. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe my createJson should also return some pointer to the last nesting location somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation of `createJson` might be a bit more efficient:

```
nlohmann::json createJson(const std::vector<std::string>& keys)
{
    nlohmann::json root;
    nlohmann::json* it = &root;
    for (auto& key : keys)
    {
        it = &((*it)[key]);
    }
    *it = nlohmann::json({});
    return root;
}
```

If you want access to the last created element you could just return it from `createJson`, note that in order for the pointer to remain valid we must pass in the root element otherwise returning it from the function will invalidate the pointer:

```
nlohmann::json* createJson(nlohmann::json& root, const std::vector<std::string>& keys)
{
    nlohmann::json* it = &root;
    for (auto& key : keys)
    {
        it = &((*it)[key]);
    }
    *it = nlohmann::json({});
    return it;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
nlohmann::json myJson;
auto it = createJson(myJson, keys);
it->merge_patch(newJson1);
```

Comment: As an alternative API, `createJson` could take a callback of type `std::function<void(json&)>` to the innermost element. That gives you client code such as `createJson({"a","b","c"}, [&](json& inner) { inner.merge_patch(newJson1); });`

Comment: @Botje I think the returned element is only going to be used later, not sure a callback will help

Comment: Yes, you return the outer shell via the normal path and allow the client code access to the innermost element via the callback. Feels a bit more functional than an out parameter.

Comment: @Botje but if you don't want to use the inner element immediately then you can't store it for later use